# Code compiler interface using C#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, process, io

I want to write a program or a class that can compile cpp codes using installed GCC compiler and if there are compilation errors: report them.

If there are no errors, then run the executable file and send inputs to and get outputs from that program, then use the outputs for other computations.

My solution is using .net `Process` class and calling `CMD` and .... but is there any better way or better .net components to write this program?

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable solution and AFAIK the only one available for GCC.

Comment: Tnx, and what about MS C++ compiler?

Comment: Why is this tagged C# when the author wans to compile C++ code using the GCC compiler?  I should add there is not .NET process.

Comment: Bcoz, I must compile the cpp code using a program written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using Process to call the commandline compilers you could use utilize [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to execute a buildscript. The advantage is that your users can make and change their own build scripts without any changes to your application. Any compiler can be plugged into MSBuild scripts and the output for errors and warnings is standardized so easily parsed by you. MSBuild comes with a runtime using .Net. See [here](http://www.odewit.net/ArticleContent.aspx?id=MsBuildApi4&lang=en) and [here](http://blog.zingersaga.net/?p=117) (deprecated) for examples. This is also how Visual Studio works. Project files are msbuild scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you offer is pretty afordable. 
Sibscribe to GCC output and read for `errs` & `warns`.

Based on architecture you gonna use you can think of use of `devenv.com` binary from VS install packet . Using that you can compile direcly `projects` or `solution`.
 Not very clear if that is what you need, but by the way, another option again to consider.

Answer (score 0):

For GCC that is basically it, no fancy solutions there.

If you want to compile MS C++ (I guess managed C++ but I'm not sure on that one) you can leverage a CodeDomProvider.

You find the CPP docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/849yhx8t%28en-US,VS.80%29.aspx)

An working exmaple of how to use it based on the CSharpProvider can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655)